# Monocross Templates for VS2012

Tags: monocross

Are there any plans for Monocross templates for VS2012  Currently I can only download the VS2010 ones.

Answer (score -1):

Stackoverflow is really for questions and answers about code problems.

For issues about product roadmaps, you would be better off looking at the individual project discussion groups.

For monocross, this means asking:

- their mailing list - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/monocross-developers
- their twitter account - https://twitter.com/Monocross_net

Comment: Hmm, this is rather bizarre again.  Companies point to Stack Overflow as a forum for answers related to their products, get tags created for that, then Stack Overflow moderators come right back at you and slap you with a "This is not a Stack Overflow appropriate question".  I guess Stack Overflow needs to decide which side of the fence it's on?